# What does the filter parameter to createScaledBitmap do?

Tags: android, scaling

The declaration of `android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` is

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap
  (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

However, the documentation doesn't explain any of the parameters.  All of them are pretty obvious except for `boolean filter`.  Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

A quick dig through the SKIA source-code indicates that (at least by default) the FILTER flag causes it to do a straightforward bilinear interpolation.  Check Wikipedia or your favorite graphics reference to see what the expected consequences are.  Traditionally, you want to do bilinear or bicubic interpolation when upsizing images, and area averaging when downsizing images.  I get the impression (though I'm glad to be corrected) that Android/Skia does simple subsampling when downsizing without filtering, so you are likely to get better results from filtering even when downsizing.  (There's an alternate method for getting high quality downsizing with interpolation, involving doing a series of 50% scale reductions.  See http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html for details.)

Comment: What does it do if you pass it false?  Nearest neighbor?

Comment: Also, do you know if it's doing area averaging if you pass filter = true?

Comment: You should add an image to get a feel for what the difference is, instead of referencing external sources. Links die, sources vanish.

Comment: Haha, more than years 10 later @clahey: `If this is false then nearest-neighbor scaling is used instead which have worse image quality but is faster. ` is in the javadoc for `createScaledBitmap`

Answer (score 259):

To expand on Karan's answer: As a general rule you won't see any difference if you're scaling your image *down*, but you will if you're scaling it *up*.

Passing `filter = false` will result in a blocky, pixellated image.

Passing `filter = true` will give you smoother edges.

However, as EIYeante pointed out in the comments, you might still see a difference. [This is their example image.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18446310/filter_parameter_example.png)

Comment: @Mirko - nah, it's OK: this should earn me the Populist badge any minute now. :)

Comment: @ElYeante - do you have an example? Some input and output images would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Wow. I stand corrected. I'm curious as to why this is so apparent with your images, but I've not seen it with mine. Is it because you're downscaling by so much, perhaps?

Comment: this flag is misleading. how can we downsample with smoothing prior to resampling to prevent anti-aliasing?

Comment: The link has broken @teedyay

Comment: @teedyay You should inline the image because links often die on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but I thought some sample images might clarify the issue.

[image: image filters compared]

There is a more general question about whether and how to filter on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/375718/which-resize-algorithm-to-choose-for-videos).

Says Jeff Atwood:

> In general you want a mild sharpening effect when making a larger image into a smaller one, and a mild blurring effect when making a smaller image into a larger one.

Android's API does not specify what kind of filter would be applied, so I guess the question is: do you want your pixels to remain as they are (as you would want in 8-bit art) or is it okay to apply a transformation to make the image more palatable (as you would want in photographs).

Answer (score 3):

Filter will set the [FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap%28boolean%29) for painting which affects the sampling of bitmaps when they are transformed based on the value that you provide.

Comment: What effect does it have on the sampling of bitmaps?

Comment: I don't know much about bitmap sampling, you can check the following wiki page for details.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29

Comment: "affects the sampling of bitmaps" in what what exactly?  Is it a good effect or a bad one?

Comment: @Willian Denniss : Check the above comment. I don't know the details and I've not tried this yet.

Answer (score 1):

During my research about used algorithm when **filter=false** (I needed to be 100% sure what output is produced) as I was using the same tensorflow lite model on android and python and found that it uses NEAREST (tested on android 7.1) when **filter=false**. I've compared embeddings which were identical on android and on python when used *PIL resample=Image.NEARES*T