# AppWidget image quality

Tags: android

I have an image with transparency which I need to place on the AppWidget. The transparent areas look fine on Motorola Droid, but on some other devices (e.g. HTC Hero) I got a lot of ugly noise. The manual says:

"In some cases, devices have low pixel depths that can cause visual banding and dithering issues. To solve this, application developers should pass assets through a "proxy" drawable defined as XML:. This technique references the original artwork, in this case "background.9.png", and instructs the device to dither it as needed."

Looks like it may be the solution. Unfortunately I need to prepare the widget image dynamically (combining a set of other images together, depending on the data received) and can not create a XML bitmap referencing a static resource.

Is there any way around this?

P.S. I've found out that even when I use a "proxy" XML bitmap with dithering enabled I still get a noise in the transparent areas :(

/Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should expect better results scaling a much higher resolution image down (e.g. higher than the HDPI image) - I'd suggest at least 2xHDPI resolutions, to avoid Nyquist artefacts like aliasing.

It's probably worth reading [What does the filter parameter to createScaledBitmap do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895065/what-does-the-filter-parameter-to-createscaledbitmap-do), as this has some interesting links.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello