# How to scale a bitmap larger than 4096 pixels?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, scale, fullscreen

I have two goals I am trying to achieve.

1. Scale a bitmap proportionately.
2. Scale the same bitmap so that its height is equal to the device's height.

When attempting this, I find that on devices with less pixels, the scaling works fine, but on devices with more pixels, the scaling forces the bitmap to reach over the **4096x4096** pixel limit:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer(10630): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4476x885, max=4096x4096)
```

As of now, I am using Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height) to scale my bitmaps:

```
float conversion = (float) view.getHeight() / (float) originalBitmap.getHeight();

Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postScale(conversion,conversion);

Bitmap resizedBitmap =
     Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap,0,0,originalBitmap.getWidth(),
     originalBitmap.getHeight(), mat, false);
imageView.setImageBitmap(resize);
```

The above code coupled with the following xml allows for the bitmap to scale the entire screen:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

If there are any other ways to proportionality scale a bitmap to the entire screen, I would greatly appreciate those suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter);`
where dstWidth and dstHeight are the desired widths and heights, respectively.  (The filter just tries to smooth edges if it is true, and doesn't if it is false, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867341/3866776).)  This does not require a Matrix parameter or a desired position, it just returns the scaled bitmap.

The following would probably work for you:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = 
     Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, 
     originalBitmap.getWidth() * (view.getHeight() / originalBitmap.getHeight()),
     view.getHeight());
imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

You also probably only need this much of the XML now:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

That's because you don't need to center something that takes up the whole of its parent, and you aren't using a matrix to scale anymore.