# Gaussian blur on RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to apply a gaussian blur effect to a view? I'd like to apply this effect to a relative layout that is over another one. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556162/2363774), but it's only for images. 
P.S.: the relative layout has a solid color (I used the setBackgroundColor method).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android you can create drawables like shapes or gradients and you can combine them together to rather complex images.

But, something complex like a Gaussian Blur is not part of it, also not with transparent colors.

The way to do that is, to create a bitmap and set the background of your Layout programmatically.

Things get worth, when you want to blurr the actual screen underlying your app. There's no way to grab the image underlying your app.