# Android - Blur an image from drawable and load it to imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview, blur

How to blur an image(png) and then load it to image view using setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.***). It must work on API > 10

I have found some solutions, but i don't know how to take image from @drawable
and load it to imageview

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these ways to set the image to `ImageView`

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

or

```
imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

or

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
imageView.setImageBitmap(drawable.getBitmap());
```

Comment: thank you,@balaji koduri, i have found method (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556162/3149274), and i don't know how to take image from @drawable and than load it to imageview using this algorithm

Comment: @HappiestGabbler it is works for you..

Answer (score 1):

This library does what you are looking for: https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur