# Android: cannot find symbol for my own imported class

Tags: android, import, android-studio

Okay, this is driving me absolutely nuts. Relevant info:

I'm using Android Studio

I'm trying to set up a gaussian blur from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556162/2170400

In my src/com/myprojectname folder I have, among others, the following files: AndroidImage.java, IAndroidFilter.java, ConvolutionMatrix.java and GaussianBlur.java. In IAndroidFilter.java I need to

```
import com.myprojectname.AndroidImage;
```

However I get a message saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidImage'". In the auto-complete menu that pops up while I'm typing the import statement I can see EVERY SINGLE CLASS in my src/com/myprojectname folder EXCEPT AndroidImage, which I can clearly see in the explorer.

I've quit and re-opened Android Studio several times, I've re-synced everything, I've deleted then re-created the AndroidImage class, I've tried to import AndroidImage in other classes with the same failed result as in the IAndroidFilter class...

Why is it that I can't import this class? Seriously, why? I'm at a total loss for further fixes to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to make sure your AndroidImage.java file has this at the top:

```
package com.myprojectname.AndroidImageProject;
```

Or whatever the package is.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even remember you needed to explicitly provide packages.. well that was an easy fix. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  I've had that happen as well.