# Blur draw on Image view

Tags: android, image, blur

I need to draw blur on image view and UnBlur also. I tried with RenderScript  but I got full image blur,can any one help me regarding libraries or coding.Like below image
Thank you, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctokv.jpg)

Comment: check this--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831617/how-to-blur-imageview-in-android                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555937/android-programmatically-blur-imageview-drawable

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice blurring library - https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur

If you write a blurring function yourself, crop only the area you need by creating a new bitmap - `Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, startX, startY, width, height)`

Comment: thanks for your quick reponse.Actually I need draw blur with finger on Image can help regarding this...thanks