# Blur algorithm for android app

Tags: android

I am looking for a blur algorithm for an android app. The algorithm I found here [Fast Bitmap Blur For Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk) doesn't work in an AsyncTask.
I receive data from a sensor over a long time (one until two houres). Depending on the data an image must be blurred more or less. All pure java code I found is not fast enough wherefore I want to access native C code over jni. Is there anybody could give a hint?

Thanks anko