# Type 'AndroidBitmapInfo' could not be resolved

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm a newbie of Android NDK. I want to try create fast blur effect to bitmap and I found a NDK solution from here: [Fast Bitmap Blur For Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk)  answered by @zeh

after I did my configuration, I am not able to run the project and It said "**Type 'AndroidBitmapInfo' could not be resolved**" in the *.c file.

Could you guys tell me how to fix this problem?

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Create BitmapUtils library

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics -landroid

LOCAL_MODULE    := bitmaputils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bitmaputils.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS    =  -ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loops

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just in case: have you correctly included the bitmap header?

```
#include <android/bitmap.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, yes I did include android/bitmap.h

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your Application.mk

`APP_PLATFORM := android-8`

In case you don't use Application.mk, run ndk-build as follows:

```
ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-8
```

Comment: I tried your solution by add them to my Android.mk under the  "include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)" line but I still show me the error.

Comment: You know Android.mk and Application.mk are two different files right? It looks like you don'T have Application.mk file and as far as I know, bitmap.h is introduced after app platform 8, so that could be the problem causing your module not to locate the header file.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that is the Application.mk not Android.mk, I just did it but the error still appear.

Answer (score 1):

according to ndk samples\bitmap-plasma\jni, you'd better double check mk file, and header file.

```
Application.mk
# The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
----------------------------------------------------------------
Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := plasma
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := plasma.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
--------------------------------------------------------
plasma.c
#include <jni.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: I just did your solution and it doesn't work. I also got the same error on Bitmap-Plasma sample project by the way.

Comment: can you successfully pass other samples by command ndk-build?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of CDT indexer needs to enable "Index unused headers ..."

To get there: Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Indexer.
Than rebuild the project 
If still this appears than repeat this again.It will be gone :)