# Custom Popupwindow for all screensize android

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am using a custom popup window. On Load I have to pass the height and width of the window. But I want to load the popup for all screensizes. I am using the below function to load my popup.

```
private void loadPopup() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_up_ad, null);

    final PopupWindow windows = new PopupWindow(layout , 300,500,true);

    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            windows.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }

    });
    ImageButton close = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
       close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             windows.dismiss();
         }
       });
}
```

I tried this one. But it completes the screen size. I don't want that much filled.

```
windows.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just detect the screen height / width and then scale down by some factor so it does not fill the screen as much as you want?

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

The above code should get you your height and width of the screen and then you can just divide or subtract down the height and width to make the pop up fill as much of the screen as you want.

was this what you wanted? or did i misunderstand?

Comment: let me try this one.

Comment: I can do with this. thanks alot ..Can you help me with blurring or dimming the background too??

Comment: like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect

Comment: if the accepted answer on that is not what you're looking for let me know

Comment: I think it's a bit complicated. and it requires min sdk to be API 17. Like in a dialog? just dim the background? Or how do I use the class in my function?

Comment: before api 17 you blurred with this: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

Comment: here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog  seems pretty similar in style to that other post.  You seem to have to do it yourself now

Comment: it throws many errors.. I am not getting them clearly. Can you help me out?

Comment: Is the above code throwing errors or is the blurred background code throwing errors? If it's the blurred background code, you should really post that as a new question, post what you have attempted, errors etc, that way the whole community can help, and additionally, you should accept this answer if it worked for answering your question.