# how to blur a dialog activity background

Tags: java, android, layout

sorry for my english :).
I need to blur my dialog activity background and I tried this method

> [Blur BackGround Behind AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog)

And I send my bitmap with this code :

```
Bitmap back1 = takeScreenShot(MainActivity.this);
Bitmap back2 = fastblur(back1, 10);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilterActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("back", back2);
startActivity(intent);
```

And recieve bitmap in my activity :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
    Bitmap back = intent.getParcelableExtra("back");
    BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), back);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
    setContentView(R.layout.filter_activity);
}
```

But it force closed for me with this error in logcat:

```
03-08 14:03:54.685 16735-16735/ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 13225428)
03-08 14:03:54.685 16735-16735/ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-08 14:03:54.686 16735-16735/ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc, PID: 16735
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
```

How can I fix this? Or do you know another way to blur the background of dialog activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first,you shouldn't translate Bitmap by Binder，the max container of binder is 1M.

You can try this:
At first:

```
MyApplication. back2 = back2;
```

then:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),MyApplication.back2);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground(ob);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filter_activity);
}
```

Comment: I didnt get this part `MyApplication. back2 = back2;`

Comment: You should add a public static variable,as follow:                                        public static Bitmap back2;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet, this will create **transparent background for Dialog**.

```
private void Dialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(GenerateToken.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_tokenvalidate);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //The below code is EXTRA - to dim the parent view by 70%
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
        lp.dimAmount = 0.7f;
        lp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new      ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        //Show the dialog
        dialog.show();
        TextView tvSelectedBank = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.validatetext);
        //button for ok
        dialog.findViewById(R.id.tokenvalidate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

also, get help from this thread [Blur Background behind AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog)

Comment: this code just transparent background not blur. you can do this just with this code in oncreate `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));`