# How can block out and darken a view when i show a popup in android?

Tags: android, view, popup

my problem by displaying a popup is that the view back is not blocked , I need block and obscure the view while the popup this over , I need the view can not be clicked , only the popup
My Popup:

```
View popupView;
PopupWindow popupWindow;
popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_ver_noconf_submateria_urgente, null);
                                    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                                    aceptar = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.acept);
                                    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            sub.activity.startActivity(new Intent(sub.activity, VerNoConformidadesSubmateria.class));
                                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                                            releaseLayout();
                                        }
                                    });
```

PD: Sorry for the bad english

Comment: Any reason why you arent using AlertDialog for this purpose? You can set custom views for an AlertDialog using `setView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blur BackGround Behind AlertDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog)