# Blur Background Behind Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, blur

I want to have blurred background for any custom dialog. And FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND was deprecated from API 14, so this

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

wont work. Also i dont want to take screenshot and then blur it and use it to blur the background.

I went through [Blur BackGround Behind AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog) but this is also not working.

I also came across this library for blurring dialog here at :  https://github.com/tvbarthel/BlurDialogFragment  but it is for DialogFragment .

Is there any other way to blur dialog background ?

Comment: What do you mean with "wont work" and "not working" ? This are proven solutions so you might be miss configuring something. Can you please post the code and the resulting screenshots ?