# AlertDialog with Blur background in position center

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, blur

**Question**

Tried to blur (not DIM) the background of a `Dialog`.

and `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` is *deprecated*.

Approach is, take a screenshot form the currant view and blur it.Then **attach to the background**,When `AlertDialog` appears,  and it works.

but `AlertDialog` is always in the Top *not* in the center.(check the image)

`WindowManager.LayoutParams` has no effect *after* attach .(before attach it to the background,alert *can* position to center, but after attaching the blur view to the background `AlertDialog` always go to the top )

How can I make my alert center in the screen?

below is code i tried,any guide will be appreciated ,

*Displayed alert when i press back.*

```
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            builder.setTitle("Lets Blur");
            builder.setMessage("This is Blur Demo");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


            dialog = builder.create();

// this position alert in the CENTER
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            dialog.show();

            new BlurAsyncTask().execute();

        }

        class BlurAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap> {


            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

                Bitmap map  = AppUtils.takeScreenShot(MainActivity.this);
                Bitmap fast = new BlurView().fastBlur(map, 10);
                return fast;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                if (result != null){
                    final Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),result);
                    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
// this position alert again in the TOP -- need to avoid that!
                    window.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
                    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    dialog.show();

                }

            }
```

Other classes

**AppUtils**

```
public class AppUtils {

    public static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {
        View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();


        Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;

        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;


        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        return b;
    }
}
```

---

**BlurView**

```
public class BlurView {

    public Bitmap fastBlur(Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);
        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;
        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];
        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }
        yw = yi = 0;
        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];
                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;
                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];
                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];
                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;
                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];
                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];
                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;
                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];
                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];
                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];
                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;
                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];
                yi += w;
            }
        }
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
        return (bitmap);
    }
}
```

screen shot - this is the result i get- i want to make alert center but it stays on top
[image: this is the result i get- i want to make it center]

**Edit : Answer's Concept**

1. Take a screen shot
2. Programmatically animate/blur/whatever effect to that screen shot
3. Get currant window using a dialog witch does not have any content
4. Attach screen shot with effect
5. Display real view I wanted to display

---

**Side Note:** This can be used to attach any type of a background! blur.. dim..bright.. Just add the right method that accept a bitmap and return a bitmap with changes you want in `BlurView` class. I added a blur one.

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: can add some screenshot ??

Comment: mmm yes i wan to keep the alert dialog in center . but when i try to do this--> window.setBackgroundDrawable(draw); it goes to the top of the screen by default

Comment: i added a screen shot as well hope now you will get what i tried to do -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This screen background can be anything you have on it,  what it does is take a screenshot of it and blur that finally set it as the background of the `alertDialog` with blur effect

Problem was `alertDialog` attached with that blur background was always on the top and i couldn't  change that.

I came up with this solution.

I had to  use two `alertDialogs` 
one is for the blur effect(for the use of `getWindow()`) and it does not get display now(I removed its `setContentView` / can use transparent background)

The other one is the real alert dialog got display after the blur effect.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  AlertDialog dialogWhichDisplayAlert;
    private  Dialog fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        //  fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.setContentView(R.layout.fakealert); // removed the content so not visible



        new BlurAsyncTask().execute();

    }

    class BlurAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Bitmap> {


        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

            Bitmap map  = AppUtils.takeScreenShot(MainActivity.this);
            Bitmap fast = new BlurView().fastBlur(map, 10);
            return fast;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            if (result != null){
                final Drawable draw=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),result);
                Window window = fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.getWindow();
                window.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.show();


                // real one
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
                builder.setTitle("Lets Blur");
                builder.setMessage("This is Blur Demo");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.dismiss();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.dismiss();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                dialogWhichDisplayAlert = builder.create();

                // position real dialogWhichDisplayAlert using Gravity.CENTER;
                dialogWhichDisplayAlert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialogWhichDisplayAlert.getWindow().getAttributes();
                wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                dialogWhichDisplayAlert.show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

[other classes used are same as the question]

**style**

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>
```

**Out put**

[image]

Comment: Here I have faced a problem that the fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect move upside.
But it has been solved by a change  window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); to  window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);