# Android change Alert Dialog underlay height

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've got an AlertDialog and I would like to change the height of the underlaying background, not the dialog itself. Haven't been able to find any source online showing if this is possible or which attributes in the alert dialog theme to manipulate. The only attribute that seems to change anything with the underlaying background is dimAmount. Here is what I have:
[image]

Here's what I would like to have:
[image]

As you can see the action bar and bottom navigation buttons are no longer being covered by the AlertDialog underlay.

Comment: whats that blue floating icon :0  new feature android xoxo check this my old answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/41373144/5188159

Comment: Do you want to place alertDialog center vertically ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam no I want decrease the height/ give the dimmed underlay top and bottom margins so you can see the top actionbar and navigation buttons on the bottom

Comment: @M. Smith well then my answer does not help you. what about having a custom view which display as an alert but just a view

Comment: Im already using a custom view with a custom class extending AlertDialog, guess I could try to replicate the dimmed background in my custom view. I was hoping there was some seldom use attribute out there in the vast R.style world lol