# How to set Blur background when dialog create

Tags: java, android, dialog, blur

How to set Blur background when dialog create?

I found `DialogFragment` only and `AlertDialog` but I want to set in `Dialog`in activity

How to create it or What's library recommend?

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        window.setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.register_policy_dialog);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**try this**

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

**or  try this you can apply a custom theme to your dialog like this**

```
Dialog customDialog= new Dialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.mytheme); 
Window window = customDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

**now create the theme like this**

```
<style name="mytheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>        
</style>
```

and also check this [AlertDialog with Blur background in possition center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421723/alertdialog-with-blur-background-in-possition-center)