# Android - Popup window crashing

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow

Searched for many solution in the stackoverflow community, but none solves my problem: I have a `button` in `Main.java` activity, when `button` is clicked, the popup menu does not show and the whole app is crashed.

**Here is my code:**

```
 Button _buyurtmaYaratish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buyurtma_berish);
    _buyurtmaYaratish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button btnPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
                btnPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnPopup, 50, -30);
            }
        });
```

**My Main.xml code:**

```
<RelativeLayout.......

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_buyurtma_berish"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buyurtma_berish"
        android:background="@drawable/button_kirish"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtx_summa_miqdori"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My popup.xml code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_kk_mas_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/aloqaga_chiqamiz"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_kirish"
        android:text="@string/tasdiqlash"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_popup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_kk_mas_popup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**What Am I doing wrong?**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                    at datasite.com.aroba.DelHome$2.onClick(DelHome.java:49)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4192)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17248)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is highlighted red in the Logcat when I try to click `button`

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: can you post what error you are getting in stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**change this** :-> 
 `Button btnPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);`

**with this** :-> `Button btnPopup = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);` in your code

**like below code**

```
     Button _buyurtmaYaratish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buyurtma_berish);
    _buyurtmaYaratish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button btnPopup = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
                btnPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnPopup, 50, -30);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Working. thanxs

Comment: i will definitely, after 7 minutes it is allowed

Comment: how can I make my the background activity to be darker when popup window is enabled

Comment: @ZafarKurbonov check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221488/blur-or-dim-background-when-android-popupwindow-active

Comment: @ZafarKurbonov and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477484/how-to-remove-transparent-dark-background-outside-of-dialog-box

Comment: @ZafarKurbonov and also check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802320/how-to-set-blur-background-when-dialog-create/45802374#45802374

Answer (score 3):

Use `Button btnPopup = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup)` instead of `Button btnPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popup)` as

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making mistake here :

```
Button btnPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
```

Change it like this:

```
Button btnPopup = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
```

Comment: Oh shit, so easy mistake i have done. now it is working! thank

Comment: It happens sometimes :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
Button btnPopup = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
```

**instead of this:**

```
Button btnPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_popup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Popup window, you had better to use AlertDialog which is not only easy to build but at the same time get similar background effects. More flexible to move/change and smoothly works