# Is there any way I can open a different view on top of another view upon pressing it for some time

Tags: java, android

I want to implement something like what instagram does here.
Upon long pressing on a post it opens up another view on top the screen to show the post and makes the remaining part of the screen blur.
[image]

Comment: Check out this article. It shows different types of dialogs as examples:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/showing-material-design-dialogs-in-an-android-app--cms-30013

Answer (score 0):

for creating something like this in android you can use alertDialog with custom layout and blur the background:
**custom_layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                  android:paddingRight="30dp"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <LinearLayout
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                  android:paddingRight="10dp"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

in **Activity**:

```
        //create an alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Name"); //you can add this to your custom layout only
        // set the custom layout
            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
            builder.setView(view);
            Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1); // etc.. for button2,3,4.
        // onclick functions
        // create and show the alert dialog
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

for blur background, you can add a theme like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41373144/7364284 but, I would suggest using window attributes like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381077/7364284 because of its less code and easy to use.