# Problem with blurred background on AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I'm tried to blur background using this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278278/10837992.

It's work good but i have a little problem with the size of the dialog.

1. I'm created custom layout :
2. I'm changed the realization of the method.

   ```
                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                   LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
                   View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);
                   builder.setView(dialogView);
                   TextView title = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
                   TextView desc = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);

                   title.setText("Title");
                   desc.setText("Desc");
                   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();


                   Bitmap map = new BlurUtils().takeScreenShot(getActivity());
                   Bitmap fast = new BlurUtils().fastblur(map, 50);
                   final Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), fast);

                   alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                   alert.show();
   ```
3. While running this method, the size of the Dialog is cropped:
   Screenshoot:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I find a solution:

Just added Theme to AlertDialog.Builder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
```