# android - Change Blur Background color behind AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I want to change the **black transparent** background to **white transparent**, tried to change it in the `AppTheme` style but it didn't work.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYjBc.png]

Also I want to change the **black blur background** to **white blur**, tried to change it in the `AppTheme` style.

I also tried renderscript, fastblur, xml mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog/21278278#21278278), but it changed only the dialog white background

[image]

Any ideas how to change it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show how you tried to change it in the theme XML? Are you using AppCompat or Material Components?

Answer (score 4):

Using the style you can change the dim not the blur.
You can use the `android:backgroundDimAmount` attribute (range: `1.0 - 0.0`):

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.xx</item>
</style>
```

and

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialAlertDialog)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .show()
```

With `0.10` and `0.90`

[image]  [image]

Comment: your solution for changing background color is work like a charm. I also wanted a blur affect. I've edited the image in my question. Do you know how can I achieve it? Thank you!