# How to make the creamy and smooth thumbnails like "WhatsApp"

Tags: android, android-image

I want to create the fade thumbnail of very small size of bitmap. I tried to create a scaled bitmap of small width and height. But the image got pixellated And the pixels look like broken.
The whatsapp thumbnails (those are received before actually receiving image message) are creamy and smooth. How to create such thumbnails

Comment: try to use 9 patch images for message bubbles.

Comment: ... creamy?! Unfortunately I uninstalled Whatsapp weeks ago (when the CIA/NSA bought it, you know...) so I can't taste these thumbnails anymore. (I don't even have a memory of those creamish things, by the way)

Comment: @ArtooDetoo You dont need to taste them! If you would be having the WhatsApp then may be after seeing the thumbnails those are received just before downloading the images you could realize what i mean. Creamy means these thumbnails look fade But the pixels of these are not scattered like if you try to adjust a small image to big surface.

Comment: Do you mean **blurred**?

Comment: @ArtooDetoo yes. almost that..

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk)