# Android : How to blur specific are in Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, blur

I'm looking for as simple as it gets api to `blur` an area (rectangle) in `Android Bitmap`.
The main idea is to detect faces (which already works) and blur the face.
I've seen several examples, most are using `RenderScript` but all relates to full picture blur.
Required API is 11+

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be API 11+? Can you do 14+?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't want this feature to prevent API 11-13.

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is for 14+, sorry

Comment: check out, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/794088

Comment: API 14+ has face detection capabilities. Than with @petey's post can possibly do it.

Comment: @petey What you mentioned is for the whole image while I need certain area.

Comment: chop it, blur it, paste it.. that's what I'm doing now :p