# Is there a faster way to draw bitmaps than with Canvas.drawBitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm using code bellow to decode bitmaps.

```
Bitmap temp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
Bitmap image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, width, height, true);
```

I'm using code bellow to draw bitmap on canvas.

```
Canvas c=SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
c.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

Is there any faster way to draw bitmaps on canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Try Native code development(NDK). The NDK development helps to fastest way to display a [Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk).

Comment: Answers should be able to stand on their own. Make sure to include relevant information and/or examples. Otherwise, write a comment for the main question.