# How to achieve a background blur like Yahoo Mail in an Android application?

Tags: android

[image]

As you can see, the menu has a clear effect, whereas the content
background is kind of a blur. And this blur effect is only to the
content. For more, you can actually see the [Yahoo Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail&hl=en).

Comment: use background image

Comment: dint get you ? I already use a background image, but i need the blur effect. You mean to say use image for that blur ?

Comment: I don't really know of a non-hacky method of doing this. Couldn't you just use two backgrounds (one blurry and one normal), that fit together?

Comment: above image is of yahoo app right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk

Comment: Yes. Its a yahoo app. I can use a blur image for the content. But the thing is the blur content image is in sync.

Comment: @Yuraj : thanks for the link, but one quick question, my app has a default common background for both drawer and the layout(content). Does the link you shared has some example to set blur effect only to the content? Im new to android :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the HTML structure and apply CSS 3 filter blur on the parent container while the parent content does not.

There is a more detailed post in Stack Overflow post *[How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image that I am setting with background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765)*.

Comment: Im looking for an android way. Not the CSS way.