# Blurred background image in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, image, android-linearlayout, blur

I saw this effect in an app named "Umano" (picture below). The background image is (I assume) loaded from a URL and added as a background to the layout BUT blurred as you can see. How can I change my code (given below) such that i can achieve this effect?

[Image Link here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10922213_10204828166919404_1491126175_n.jpg?oh=3d94c2f6f17b37b3183e6ab8c6646044&oe=54BB254E&__gda__=1421544227_a4d44cd2ffc53390f8431fef968c418a)

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/dragView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#eeeeee"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Product Details"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
             </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can set background of Linear layout
 android:background="#80000000" for opacity

Comment: What if I'm having an image like illustrated in the picture? @ShoebAhmedSiddique

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain blurred images using **[Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html)**.

[Here's](https://plus.google.com/+MarioViviani/posts/fhuzYkji9zz) an official tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some blurring algorithm over the image and then set it up as your background image in the layout.

You may find very useful the following links:

http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/

[Fast Bitmap Blur For Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk)

Regards,
Néstor