# How to add a blurry effect on drawable image through XML in android

Tags: android

How can I add a blur effect on a drawable image placed in the image view object of a layout, using xml not Java? I want to code this blur effect in XML.

Answer (score 4):

It is **not** currently possible to produce a blur effect within the layout XML of an Android application.

However, it *is* possible through the use of Java. There are a number of techniques available to do this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23119957/717778) for a recent guide on how to do this effectively). Usually either `Renderscript` or the re-scaling of the image is used to generate a blur of the image.

Edit:

It *may* now be possible to achieve a blur solely by adding an XML property through the use of a custom data binding adapter. Check out the [data binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) for more on how to create an adapter