# How to blur the whole screen except from a button

Tags: android, button, blur

I have looked around a lot and have seen some examples and this: [question](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwiW6OaaqtTIAhWFOhQKHUoADVE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F33014203%2Fandroid-blur-out-screen-on-clicking-a-button&usg=AFQjCNH-Brslhjv6S7ijRo2JRAM3xWxaLA&bvm=bv.105454873,bs.1,d.d24&cad=rja) but I don't want to blur only a background pic and whats more only .png format (because unless I am wrong this method does not work on .jpg).

I want to blur everything on screen except from one button, not make everything transparent except from the button or only my bg and leave the rest as is!

I was trying to use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/3065448) but I don't know to blur the buttons as well.