# How to set blur images load from url in Android Studio

Tags: android, blur

I have a link is a images. Now I want to load this image and blur it in images Android Studio.

This is my class. This is blur it from url but it fails.

```
 private void blurBackGround() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(dmMember.getMemberImage());
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

This is blur images

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
    if (null == image) return null;

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
    final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

    //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "LocalSuppress"}) ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution already over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028267/842607

He has used box blur and a gaussian blur. Here is the code for reference, just in case link disappears

```
/**
 * Stack Blur v1.0 from
 * http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
 * Java Author: Mario Klingemann <mario at quasimondo.com>
 * http://incubator.quasimondo.com
 *
 * created Feburary 29, 2004
 * Android port : Yahel Bouaziz <yahel at kayenko.com>
 * http://www.kayenko.com
 * ported april 5th, 2012
 *
 * This is a compromise between Gaussian Blur and Box blur
 * It creates much better looking blurs than Box Blur, but is
 * 7x faster than my Gaussian Blur implementation.
 *
 * I called it Stack Blur because this describes best how this
 * filter works internally: it creates a kind of moving stack
 * of colors whilst scanning through the image. Thereby it
 * just has to add one new block of color to the right side
 * of the stack and remove the leftmost color. The remaining
 * colors on the topmost layer of the stack are either added on
 * or reduced by one, depending on if they are on the right or
 * on the left side of the stack.
 *  
 * If you are using this algorithm in your code please add
 * the following line:
 * Stack Blur Algorithm by Mario Klingemann <mario@quasimondo.com>
 */

public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, float scale, int radius) {

    int width = Math.round(sentBitmap.getWidth() * scale);
    int height = Math.round(sentBitmap.getHeight() * scale);
    sentBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sentBitmap, width, height, false);

    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

    if (radius < 1) {
        return (null);
    }

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pix = new int[w * h];
    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    int wm = w - 1;
    int hm = h - 1;
    int wh = w * h;
    int div = radius + radius + 1;

    int r[] = new int[wh];
    int g[] = new int[wh];
    int b[] = new int[wh];
    int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
    int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

    int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
    divsum *= divsum;
    int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
    for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
        dv[i] = (i / divsum);
    }

    yw = yi = 0;

    int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
    int stackpointer;
    int stackstart;
    int[] sir;
    int rbs;
    int r1 = radius + 1;
    int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
    int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
            sir = stack[i + radius];
            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
            rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
            gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
            bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }
        }
        stackpointer = radius;

        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            r[yi] = dv[rsum];
            g[yi] = dv[gsum];
            b[yi] = dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (y == 0) {
                vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
            }
            p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi++;
        }
        yw += w;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        yp = -radius * w;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

            sir = stack[i + radius];

            sir[0] = r[yi];
            sir[1] = g[yi];
            sir[2] = b[yi];

            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

            rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
            gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
            bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }

            if (i < hm) {
                yp += w;
            }
        }
        yi = x;
        stackpointer = radius;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
            pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (x == 0) {
                vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
            }
            p = x + vmin[y];

            sir[0] = r[p];
            sir[1] = g[p];
            sir[2] = b[p];

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[stackpointer];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi += w;
        }
    }

    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    return (bitmap);
}
```

Comment: But how to blur image from url? Where i can copy a link?

Comment: You can download image using okhttp3 library or you can even process using Picasso library

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BlurredAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private Context context;
    private ImageView iv;
    private int radius;

    public BlurredAsynctask(Context context, ImageView iv, int radius) {
        this.context = context;
        this.iv = iv;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            url = null;
        }

        try {
            if (url != null) {
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());
            return image;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            Bitmap bm = CreateBlurredImage(result, radius);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap CreateBlurredImage(final Bitmap bm, int radius) {
        Bitmap blurredBitmap;
        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation input;
        input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bm,
            Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        script.setRadius(radius);
        script.setInput(input);
        blurredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), 
            bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Allocation output;
        output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
        script.forEach(output);
        output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);
        script.destroy();
        return blurredBitmap;
    }
}
```

Add this code in MainActivity

```
final ImageView iv_profilepic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_profilepic);
final BlurredAsynctask task = new BlurredAsynctask(this, iv_profilepic, 25);

task.execute("https://secure.i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03597/POTD_chick_3597497k.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bluer {
private static final float SCALE = 1.7f;
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25f;

public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * SCALE);
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * SCALE);
    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);
    RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur intrinsicBlur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    Allocation tmIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
    intrinsicBlur.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    intrinsicBlur.setInput(tmIn);
    intrinsicBlur.forEach(tmOut);
    tmOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

}

```
 Bitmap outputBitmap = Bluer.blur(this, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1));
    imageview.setImageBitmap(outputBitmap);
```